# Normal vector field of $I \times_f S^n$

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, vector-fields

Let $I$ be an interval and $f \colon I \to \mathbb{R}$ is a positive function such that $M = I \times_f S^n(1)$ is the warped product Riemannian manifold, which is a hypersurface in $\mathbb{R}^{n+2}$. Here $I$ denotes an interval and $S^n(1)$ is the unit sphere, both equipped with their standard metric. I'm now asked to determine the normal vector field of $M$. The normal vector field is of course the vector field that is normal to $T_pM$. But $T_pM = T_pI \oplus T_pS^n(1)$ so I think that it is enough to find a normal vector field on $I$ and $S^n(1)$. The normal vector field on $S^n(1)$ is of course just the position vector but I'm not sure what the normal vector on the interval is, nor if my approach is correct.

EDIT: the immersion is given by

$\varphi : I \times S^n \to \mathbb{R}^{n+2} : (t, y_0,...,y_n) \mapsto \big(\alpha_1(t), \alpha_2(t)y_0,..., \alpha_2(t)y_n\big) $

where $\alpha \colon I \to \mathbb{R}^{2}$ is an arc lenght parametrised curve with $\alpha_2(t) > 0$.

Comment: This is the same question you posted earlier, and several of us asked you how precisely $M$ is embedded. Knowing the metric does not tell you this, as we told you before. It is not good form on MSE to remove a question that has been commented on and post the question anew.

Comment: I'm sorry, I have added the immersion to this question. But you are wrong about my other question: it was about the shape operator and its eigenvalues and for that exercise I had no immersion that I could use, it was only given for this specific exercise

Comment: There's no way to calculate the shape operator without an embedding. These are essentially the same question. OK, finally, we have the embedding. Can you write down a basis for the tangent space in terms of the tangent space of the sphere and the derivative of $\alpha$?

Comment: The tangent space of the unit sphere $S^n$ at $y = (y_0,...,y_n)$ is the plane given by the equation $y_0x_0+...+y_nx_n = 0$, so if the vectors $v_1,...,v_n$ form a basis for this plane then $(0,v_1),...,(0,v_n)$ are basis tangent vectors for the tangent space of $I \times S^n$ at $(t,y)$. So I still need one basis vector for the tangent space at $T_tI$ but I'm not sure how

Comment: Work this out first for $I\times S^1\to\Bbb R^3$.

Comment: I really don't know what to do. Do I need to find the derivative map and I then conclude something for the basis?

Comment: How did you find the normal to a parametrized surface when you took multivariable calculus? Go back and review.

Comment: So the Jacobian matrix of $I \times S^1 \to \mathbb{R}^3$
 at $(t,y_0,y_1)$ is given by
 
 $J_{t,y_0,y_1} = \begin{pmatrix}
 \alpha_1' & 0 & 0\\
 \alpha_2'y_0 & \alpha_2 & 0\\
 \alpha_2'y_1 & 0 & \alpha_2
 \end{pmatrix}$
 
 So the tangent space at $(t,y_0,y_1)$ is spanned by the column vectors of the Jacobian matrix evaluated at this point, so a normal vector is given by a vector $V = (u,v,w)^T$ such that $J_{(t,y_0,y_1)}V = 0$, right?

Comment: Or should I have worked with only two parameters by putting $y_1 = \sqrt{1-y_0^2}$?

Comment: How is your $f$ related to $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$?

Comment: This immersion defines a warped product metric on $I \times S^n$ with warping function $\alpha_2(t)$